# Вернуть объект инициализирующий последнее событие

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Добрый день, уважаемые коллеги!

Есть небольшая задача, есть объект javascript

```
var obj = {
    up:function(id,type)
    {
        //Необходимо вернуть объект, вызвавший эту функцию
    }
    down:function(id,type)
    {
        //Тоже самое
    }
}
```

И есть несколько объектов на странице вызывающих эти действия, допустим:

```
<!--В начале страницы-->
<div class="rating">
    <i class="icon-plus" onClick="obj.up(1,'page')"></i>
    <b>0</b>
    <i class="icon-minus" onClick="obj.down(2,'page')"></i>
</div>

<!--В конце страницы-->
<div class="rating">
    <i class="icon-plus" onClick="obj.up(1,'page')"></i>
    <b>0</b>
    <i class="icon-minus" onClick="obj.down(2,'page')"></i>
</div>
```

Ну и соответственно, мне нужно в функции получить объект который запустил 
ту функцию, чтобы я потом смог изменить значение <b>0</b> именно в том блоке .rating, в котором произошло событие.

Не подскажите ли, как лучше реализовать?

Comment: `obj.down(2,'page',this);` либо вешать хэндлер используя js вместо `onclick=""` this.nextSibling будет  ваш элемент  `b`

Comment: Хотел обойтись без третьего параметра this, но видимо не судьба. а вешать события на объекты дом, хм...можно попробовать)

Comment: Может я еще не проснулся и чего-то не понял, но [разве так нельзя](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/qU2ES/2/)?P.S. Таки не проснулся )) Не учел передаваемые значения. Но можно сделать [таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/qU2ES/3/).